# Adding metadata to non-atomic expressions in Associations and Dataset

Tags: data, dataset, associations

`Information` and `Attributes` require arguments to be symbols and strings , whether built in or user-defined.

there's often the need to associate metadata to values and as transparently as possible.

Eg, metadata about imputed Missing values:

`original = <|"a"-> DateObject[{2017,8,24}],"b"-> Missing[]|>`

How to add and extract information, to the imputed value at "b". It seems convenient to wrap something like `meta` here:

`imputed = <|"a"->DateObject[{2017,8,24}], "b"-> meta[DateObject[{2017,1,1}],"method 1"] |>`

So that metadata is transparent to most functions except specific metadata management functions like extracting, modifying or hiding?

This first cut using UpValues is my first approach but obviously conflicts with Dataset:

Transparency to most functions f:

```
meta /: f_[meta[data_, md_]] := meta[f[data], md]
```

Extraction:

```
meta /: getMetadata[meta[data_, md_]] := md

getMetadata[expr_ /; MatchQ[expr, Except[meta]]] := {}
```

Application to imputed above. Extraction:

```
imputed // Map[getMetadata]
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> {}, "b" -> "method_1"|>
> ```

Transparent function application on underlying data value:

```
imputed // Map[# - DateObject[{2001, 9, 11}] &]
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> Quantity[2174, "Days"], 
>   "b" -> meta[Quantity[1939, "Days"], "method_1"]|>
> ```

But even the first step of adding meta seeems to break Dataset type system and formatting:

```
Dataset[imputed]
```

> ```
> Dataset[<|"a" -> DateObject[{2017, 8, 24}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.],
>   "b" -> meta[DateObject[{2017, 1, 1}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], 
>     "method_1"]|>, 
>  Struct[{"a", "b"}, {Atom[DateObject], 
>    meta[Atom[DateObject], "method_1"]}], <|"ID" -> 
>    18813447225258419|>]
> ```

The underlying Association seems ok:

```
Dataset[imputed] // Normal
```

> ```
>  <|"a" -> DateObject[{2017, 8, 24}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], 
>    "b" -> meta[DateObject[{2017, 1, 1}, "Day", "Gregorian", -7.], "method_1"]|>
> ```

But that this approach doesn't play nice with Dataset is a nonstarter. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 8):

### Preamble

This is a good question. I will suggest a solution based on a concept of "disappearing wrapper". Namely, I suggest that you use a symbolic wrapper around your data, that would disappear in formatting, and mostly disappear when you apply functions to your data. However, the workings of `Dataset` will be subtly redefined, so hopefully all its useful behavior will be recovered.

### Code

Here is the code for the wrapper:

```
ClearAll[MetadataWrapper, $inDeduceType];
MetadataWrapper /: Dataset[MetadataWrapper[data_]]:=
  Block[{meta},
    MetadataWrapper @@ {Dataset[data]}
  ];

$nontransparentHeadPattern = Alternatives[
  Set, List, If, Apply
];  

MetadataWrapper /: call: ((f:Except[$nontransparentHeadPattern])[
  left___, MetadataWrapper[data_], right___
]):=
  With[{result = f[left, data, right]},
    If[FreeQ[result, meta], 
      Return[result];
    ];
    Apply[MetadataWrapper, {result}] /; !MatchQ[
      HoldComplete @ call, HoldComplete[MetadataWrapper[result]]
    ]
 ]; 

MetadataWrapper[d_Dataset][args___]:=
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{TypeSystem`DeduceType},
    TypeSystem`DeduceType[data_] /;!TrueQ[$inDeduceType]:=
      Block[{$inDeduceType = True},
        TypeSystem`DeduceType[
          ReplaceAll[data, meta[arg_,___]:>RuleCondition @ arg]
        ]
      ];
      With[{result = d[args]},
        If[MatchQ[result, _Dataset],
          MetadataWrapper @@ {result},
          result
        ]
      ]
  ];

MetadataWrapper /: MakeBoxes[wr : MetadataWrapper[data_], StandardForm]:=
  MakeBoxes[data,  StandardForm];
```

And here is the code for your `meta`, essentially unchanged, except that I added a formatting rule so that it will display as a data with metadata as tooltip:

```
ClearAll[meta];
meta/:f_[meta[data_,md_]]:=meta[f[data],md]

meta/:getMetadata[meta[data_,md_]]:=md

getMetadata[expr_ /; MatchQ[expr,Except[meta]]]:={}

meta /: MakeBoxes[meta[data_, info_], StandardForm]:=
  MakeBoxes[Tooltip[data, info]];
```

### Examples

I will use your original example. First, we create the wrapped data from your data:

```
impmeta  = MetadataWrapper[imputed]
```

This works as before (except being wrapped in `MetadataWrapper`):

```
Map[getMetadata] @ impmeta

(* <|"a" -> {}, "b" -> "method 1"|> *)
```

And so does this:

```
impmeta // Map[# - DateObject[{2001, 9, 11}] &]
```

where, however, tooltips from metadata are masked by tooltips from `Quantity`, so you have to check the `FullForm` to see that `meta` is still there.

Now, let us use `Dataset`. You can check that these inputs will work and produce the expected `Dataset` (wrapped in `MetadataWrapper`) with a proper formatting:

```
dsmeta = Dataset[impmeta]
dsmeta[All, getMetadata]
dsmeta[All, # - DateObject[{2001, 9, 11}] &]
dsmeta[All, # - DateObject[{2001, 9, 11}] &][All, getMetadata]
```

### Notes

The most ambiguous and dangerous rule to watch out for is the one with the signature `(f:Except[$nontransparentHeadPattern])[left___, MetadataWrapper[data_], right___]`. The list of heads in `$nontransparentHeadPattern` is rather arbitrary, and if some head is missed, it is likely to produce an infinite iteration and recursion when the code hits that missed head. So, a safer (but longer) version would be to curate specific list of heads and overload on those.

Other than that, this can be a start. I don't claim that this is a complete solution, it most certainly contains bugs and needs more work. Rather, this can be used as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks Leonid - this is an interesting concept - disappearing wrapper. Let me test this. Dataset's type system is a bit of mystery to me despite using it for 3 years now. Yet that's where the problems seem to lie.

Comment: @alancalvitti Yes, Dataset's type system is both its strength and its weakness. Glad if this helped. It was an interesting exercise for me.

Comment: just getting back to this and realizing I need this behavior not just for `Dataset` but for arbitrary expressions, similar to `Annotation` except the latter is visible: given `Association["a"->1,"b"->Annotation[2,"imputed"]]`,  evaluating `Map[Head]` unfortunately gives `Annotation` for "b". Instead want something transparent - or hidden - except for special functions that unhide or return the annotation. Feasible with UpValues mechanism?

Comment: @alancalvitti Depends on how general you need it to be. But this approach is error-prone unless you are able to replace generic patterns like the one I warned about, with more specific patterns - which necessarily makes it less general. If you want to enable arbitrary expressions to be annotated, a better approach would be to construct a special data structure like `AnnotatedExpression` (you can make it look like a usual expression via special formatting), and *then* define a set of functions to work on that structure, like e.g. `Annotated[Map]`, `Annotated[Apply]`, etc. (or other names).

Comment: a special data structure eg `HiddenAnnotation[expr,data]` is just what I imagine. However, there should only be a main (`UpValue`) definition to make it transparent to *all* functions except for any other specific definitions to unhide or extract the annotations.  If one is forced to overload basically all WL functions that's a non-starter.